# Grub in rescue mode after (failed) upgrade to 12.04

Tags: grub2

I am an 81 year old pretty much newbie.  I decided to upgrade my netbook to 12.04 from a USB and got an error message: "the symbol 'grub_xputs' not found" and a grub rescue prompt.  My eee 901 has a (faster) 4g SSD (sda1) and a (slower) 16g SSD (sdb1).  As I have done in the past, I mounted / on the little drive and /home on the big one.  I tried to install boot-repair from the USB but was unsuccessful. What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across http://www.geekmitra.com/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html.  PROBLEM SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ISO with pre-installed Boot-Repair, for example [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) or [Ubuntu-Secure-Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix).